# Invertified Right and Left Justify On Same Line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two justified p tags on the same line but unlike the usual I want the right justified p tag on the left and the left justified p tag on the right.  For some reason it will only show one or the other.  In hopes to help you understand better I am showing below.

```
[text:] space here  [text]
[text:] space here  [text]
[text:] space here  [text]


[text:] - Should be right justified
[text] - Should be left justified
```

I had them as two separate columns but I want to put them both in an accordion type drop down effect so I need them together.

Here is what I was trying:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <p>location:</p>
    <p>1 View Street #3 Worcester, MA 01610</p>

    <p class="break">mobile:</p>
    <p class="break"><a href="tel://860.681.8260">860.681.8260</a></p>

    <p>email:</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:marques.crosby@gmail.com">marques.crosby@gmail.com</a></p>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 50px;}

.header p {
float: left;
clear: both;
text-align: right;
margin: 0;
color: #333333;
font: italic .9em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}

.header p:nth-of-type(2n) {
float: right;
clear: none;
text-align: left;
color: #333333;
font: .9em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
padding-right: 462px;}
```

Thanks,
Marques

Comment: Where's your code, what have you tried?

Comment: an accordion type drop down effect ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give any html or css to go off of (that is not good practice for questions on Stack Overflow), but if I gather what you want based off your description, either of the following code ideas works.

### A Float Example

[**See Example in Action**](http://jsfiddle.net/h89C5/2/)

**Example HTML**

```
<p>Left text, Right align 1</p>
<p>Right text, Left align 1</p>
<p>Left text, Right align 2</p>
<p>Right text, Left align 2</p>
<p>Left text, Right align 3</p>
<p>Right text, Left align 3</p>
<p>Left text, Right align 4</p>
<p>Right text, Left align 4</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
}
p:nth-of-type(2n) {
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

### An Inline-Block Example

[**See Example in Action**](http://jsfiddle.net/h89C5/14/)

Same HTML as above, with **this CSS**:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
p:nth-of-type(2n) {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: -4px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

For the reason why the `margin-left: -4px` (and other possible solutions) [see this article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: Thank you and I will be sure to post my code next time, i didn't think it would be of assistance in this case. Looks like my issue was that you need to define a width for this to work.

Comment: You will want to define a width if you intend to keep the "center" of the two aligned in some way. Notice the [long text here](http://jsfiddle.net/h89C5/13/), which you may want to adjust by `vertical-align: top` as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h89C5/12/).